# Python websockets, always listen for messages, with occasional sending of messages called by another function

Tags: python, websocket

I've been stuck on this for a while, hopefully someone can shed some light!

I want to set up a websocket connection between JavaScript in a browser, and a Python function (currently using the websockets module).

- The Python function should always `listen()` for messages send by the browser
- Occasionally I want to send messages to the browser from an external script or function, for example by calling a function `speak()`

Here is my code currently:

`listen`

```py
async def listen(self, websocket, path):
    while True:
        need_update = await websocket.recv()
        print(f'< {need_update}')


start_server = websockets.serve(listen(), 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

`speak`

```py
async def speak(data):
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(data)
        print(f'> {data}')


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(speak(input("? ")))
```

With this method, the `speak` function will only send messages to the Python `listen` function, the JavaScript code receives nothing.

Conversely, I can start both functions together with `asyncio.gather(...)` but then I can't call `speak` from an external function.

Really not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never managed to work this out, but switching to the socket.io library solves the problem I was having.